# How can I group by (like an Excel pivot table?) my minute bar data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [1M].[FLOWERS](
    [utcDT] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Symbol] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Open] [float] NULL,
    [High] [float] NULL,
    [Low] [float] NULL,
    [Close] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How can I create a table such that I get a column for each different [Symbol] and value in column is the [Close] grouped by [utcDT]

Assume there are 10 different symbols.

I want:

```
utcDT,Symbol1,Symbol2,...,Symbol10
10:23,1.1    ,1.2    ,...,1.07
10:24,1.3    ,1.2    ,...,1.09
10:25,1.2    ,1.3    ,...,1.10
```

In Excel this is easily done with a pivot table. How can I achieve this in SQL?

Comment: PIVOT https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
SELECT [utcDT], [1] Symbol1 ,[2] Symbol2,[3] Symbol3,[4] Symbol4,[5] Symbol5,[6] Symbol6,[7] Symbol7,[8] Symbol8,[9] Symbol9,[10] Symbol10 FROM (
    SELECT CAST([utcDT] AS time) [utcDT] , [Close], [Symbol] FROM FLOWERS ) SRC
PIVOT( MAX( [Close]) FOR [Symbol] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])) PVT
```

If you want to make it dynamically you can use this.

```
DECLARE @ColNamesForPivot VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @ColNamesForSelect VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT  
    @ColNamesForPivot =  @ColNamesForPivot + ', ' + QUOTENAME([Symbol]) 
    ,@ColNamesForSelect =  @ColNamesForSelect + ', '+ QUOTENAME([Symbol]) + ' '+ QUOTENAME('Symbol' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Symbol])) 
FROM FLOWERS
GROUP BY [Symbol]


DECLARE @SqlQ NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'SELECT [utcDT] ' + @ColNamesForSelect + ' FROM (
    SELECT CAST([utcDT] AS time) [utcDT] , [Close], [Symbol] FROM FLOWERS ) SRC
PIVOT( MAX([Close]) FOR [Symbol] IN (' + STUFF(@ColNamesForPivot,1,1,'') + ')) PVT'

EXEC(@SqlQ)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT utcDT
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN Symbol = 'Symbol1' THEN [Close] END) AS Symbol1
  --,...
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN Symbol = 'Symbol10' THEN [Close] END) AS Symbol10
FROM tab
GROUP BY utcDT
ORDER BY utcDT;
```

Comment: Ok, but can I do it without having to specify each Symbol? They can vary for different datasets

Comment: @ManInMoon You can't, at least not without dynamic SQL. No matter if you use PIVOT or this method.